# Can I force a proxy to perform a fresh query instead of returning a cached response?

Tags: python, apache, nginx

I've been using a proxy to query a few websites but the websites return cache-control headers that the proxy is using. Is there anyway/headers I can pass to the proxy to force it to perform a fresh request?

I've tried to use `Cache-Control': 'no-cache'` and `'pragma': 'no-cache'` without any success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a random query string to the url.

For example

```
https://www.google.com/?random=<a ranodom value each time>
```

Comment: Massive thanks, this is working as far as I can tell.